# Magento 2 | Print php in template file

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

I got this .phtml file:

How can I make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: Update the pull path of file and the whole code of that file to the question

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: What is the layout file?

Comment: I updated it again. It's all working except the code at the end.

Comment: $this->getFormUrl() instead of $block->getFormUrl()

Comment: I updated it again with a picture.

Comment: do you have short_open_tag enabled at all? also you have to use 'echo' .. like so: `<?php echo $this->doSomething(); ?> `

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
<?= $block->getFormUrl() ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $block->getFormUrl() ?>
```

or

```
<?= $this->getFormUrl() ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getFormUrl() ?>
```

instead of yours

```
<? $block->getFormUrl() ?>
```

You have missed = in your php tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend php short_open_tags. Causes more issues than its worth.

1) are short_open_tags enabled on your server?

2) you have to use echo to print something:

`<?php echo $this->doSomething(); ?>`

Comment: Magento now uses the short tags btw.

Comment: That is  not entirely true as far as i can tell. It uses the `<?=` tag for echoing links or form actions, but it still uses `<?php` for pretty much everything else. It should also be noted that `<?=` is available without having to enable short_open_tags in your php.ini. Had a quick check in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

Comment: Isn't `<?=` the equivalent of `<?php echo`? .

And just check out any template you'll see they have replaced `<?php echo` with `<?=`. First template I went to - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml

The template you mention also uses shorthand - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: Even pages completely unrelated to forms are using the shorthand - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/frontend/templates/content.phtml

Comment: Exactly as I said. It is not, however, using short open tags which requires php.ini settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the echo

```
<?php echo $block->getFormUrl() ?>
```